# Prove that $f_{n}(z)=\frac{z + n}{n}$ does not converge uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $(f_n )_n$ be a sequence of functions $f_n:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with $f_{n}(z)=\frac{z + n}{n}$ and $U \subset \mathbb{C}$.

I think I understand the concept of uniform convergence but I'm struggling to prove that this sequence does not converge uniformly. How can I do that?

Comment: What set is $U$?

Comment: $U$ is any set in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: This cannot be. For example, if you let $U=\{0\}$, $\forall n f_n(z)=1$, and thus the convergence is uniform

Comment: In fact this converges uniformly on any bounded region $U$.

Comment: If we require $U$ to be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ then, is there any $U$ such that $f_n$ converge uniformly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence of functions converges pointwise to $1$. If $U\supset\Bbb N$, then $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):f_n(n)=2$, and therefore $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converge uniformly to $1$. Of course, for certain sets $U$ it does.